# The use of the verb abstract in a question

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive

Is this correct?

*What Java object type would abstract the number of apples to?*

The context: An apple or another real-world object can be abstracted into a specific object in the Java programming language. I am trying to ask the other person what Java object type they would use abstract to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking - the verb needs a subject.

*What Java object type would **you** abstract the number of apples to?*

Alternatively you can put it in the passive voice:

*What Java object type would the number of apples be abstracted to?*

On more of a technical level, I probably wouldn't use *abstract* for assigning a simple count of the number of objects, only when there is more indirection at play.  But I assume this is just a simplified example for the sake of the English question, and the real situation is a more complex refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on stevekeiretsu's answer, "abstract" needs a subject, and with your current wording, the only one available is the interrogative pronoun "what". That leaves "to" without an object.

And you're a bit ambiguous whether you're abstracting the *number* of apples or the apples themselves. The former can be handled just with the existing object type of integer.